# Custom Page layout shows wrong time for date fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

**Problem**

I created a custom Page layout in Sharepoint Online and everything is working well until I noticed that the modified and created time is wrong (it adds 2 hours).

**Example**

*If the page is modified at 14.07 the page layout shows 16.07.*

**Code**

`<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Modified" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:FieldValue>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong control!

Change it to:

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Modified" runat="server" />
```

[Be careful when working with date & time in SharePoint](https://francoisverbeeck.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/sharepoint-tip-of-the-day-be-careful-when-wor/)